# Intialization of 2d array in python

Tags: python

I know there are many similar questions like this but I am not sure why my code doesn't work.
Basically, what I am trying to do is to initialize a 2D array to all 0s, get user input (row, column), and set the position to 1.

```
def printBoard(positions):
    for row in positions:
        print(row)

def main()
    x= int(input())
    column = [0] * x
    Board= [column] * x
    printBoard(Board)
    for i in range(x):
        row, column = map(int, input().split())
        Board[row][column] = 1
        printBoard(Board)

main()
```

But the output is now what I expect.

```
>>>2 
[0, 0]
[0, 0]
>>>1,1
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
```

As you can see, the whole column is changed. May I ask why?

Comment: It is a mess :) for cycle is totally unnecessary. Split the initialization, asking and setting a single field to separate functions. Good luck with your game!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute

```
Board= [column] * x
```

it will result in a list in which all rows (i.e. internal lists) will be the same object (`x` times the list `column`), so when you update any element of any of those (same) lists, you will see the result `x` times, since all the rows (or columns as you call it) are exactly the same, because they are the instances of the same object.